# Spark Framework: Match with or without trailing slash

Tags: java, routes, spark-java, spark-framework

I have noticed something in the Spark Framework.  It does not match trailing slashes with a mapped route.  So it considers /api/test and /api/test/ as different URIs.

That's fine if there is a way to wildcard them together, but there doesn't seem to be.  Am I missing anything?

I want this route:

```
Spark.get("/api/test", (req, res) -> {
            return "TEST OK";
        });
```

To match /api/test OR /api/test/.  As it stands, it only matches /api/test, and if I switch it to:

```
Spark.get("/api/test/", (req, res) -> {
            return "TEST OK";
        });
```

It only matches `/api/test/`

Comment: I know nothing of spark... but if the URI isa regex, then you could add a **?** after the last **/**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can setup a *before* filter with a redirect, such as:

```
Spark.before((req, res) -> {
    String path = req.pathInfo();
    if (path.endsWith("/"))
        res.redirect(path.substring(0, path.length() - 1));
});
```

This is probably better than mapping duplicate routes.

Comment: A better option

Answer (score 7):

It seems to be asked before in 2013, but closed (and I assume not implemented) in 2015:

https://github.com/perwendel/spark/issues/97

> Routes should match with and without trailing slash #97
>
> jsnoriegam opened this issue on Aug 31, 2013
>
> ryber added a commit to ryber/spark that referenced this issue on Oct 14, 2013
>
> tipsy added the Feature request label on Nov 22, 2015
>
> perwendel closed this on Nov 23, 2015

There was a pull request by ryber with a fix for this issue:

https://github.com/ryber/spark/commit/556597e679dc224719188f8d27d8ba10e58fd8bb

However, this does not seem to be part of the current `SimpleRouteMatcher` class:

https://github.com/perwendel/spark/blob/ded78b7fa9b78749c0d5f6776bba9c9cd3cfb6fb/src/main/java/spark/route/SimpleRouteMatcher.java

Comment: I suppose I'll have to map each route both with and without a trailing slash.  Bleh.

Comment: Or dive into the Spark code and suggest another pull request, but it's not clear whether that will be accepted. Good luck anyway.

Comment: I think usually (e.g. Sinatra?) will allow a regex, so you'd be able to end with `/?`. That could be nice.